# Do Custom Metadata Queries Count Against Query or Query Row Limits?

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

According to the [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_custom_metadata.htm) for Custom Metadata Types:

> Use SOQL queries to retrieve data from custom metadata types and their records. Unlike other Apex transactions, you can make unlimited SOQL queries for custom metadata types and records.

The [Custom Metadata Allocations and Usage Calculations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=5) help doc also states unlimited queries can be issued.

The phrasing *you can make unlimited SOQL queries* strongly implies that neither the query limit nor the row limit apply when retrieving these records. Is that the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The query limit does not apply (unless you select a rich text field). However, *the row limit still applies*. This conclusion can easily be proven by running a simple script:

```
List<My_Metadata__mdt> metadata = [SELECT DeveloperName FROM My_Metadata];
system.assertEquals(0, Limits.getQueryRows(), 'This assertion fails because the row limit is consumed');
```